# Titanium appcelerator - PayPal module, transactionID?

Tags: titanium, paypal

I just added the paypal module to my application on Titanium...
Everything seems to be working fine...
There is an eventListener,"paymentsuccess"...in wich I get the transactionID...
My question is there any way to send the the transactionID back to paypal for more buyer's details: email,phone....but not via the server?

I mean I found some paypal code how to do it with PHP,but the question is ...
Can I do it directly from Titanium to Paypal?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misread my quick look-up of appcelerator Titanium, it supports PHP, Python and Ruby. Which means you should be able to use the PHP code you found if it does what you wish.

Just to be sure you found the correct PHP code, you should be using the [GetTransactionDetails API from PayPal](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_GetTransactionDetails).

The fact that you're using a framework/platform/cms shouldn't matter, as long as you can call the PHP code somehow.